# Issue with CallBackPanel's PerformCallback rendering blank chart if a chart is added to panel's controls in Page_Load

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, webforms, devexpress

I am having an issue with a WebForms page where if I bind data to a `DevExpress WebChartControl` and add it to a `DevExpress ASPxCallBackPanel` in the Page_Load, the panel's CallBack renders a blank chart when I call it via the `onChange` event of a `DropDownList`.

If I don't add the chart to the panel in Page_Load, the `CallBack` works as expected and I can re-bind different data sets to the chart based on what choice is chosen from the `DropDownList`.

Relevant code from behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {

        List<CompanyRecord> companiesList = new List<CompanyRecord>();
        List<DataWeekRecord> dataList = new List<DataWeekRecord>();

        //Data binding of various controls

        WebChartControl testChart_2 = new WebChartControl();

        testChart_2.Series.Add(new DevExpress.XtraCharts.Series("Test Series", DevExpress.XtraCharts.ViewType.Line));
        testChart_2.Series[0].ArgumentScaleType = DevExpress.XtraCharts.ScaleType.DateTime;
        testChart_2.Series[0].ValueScaleType = DevExpress.XtraCharts.ScaleType.Numerical;

        testChart_2.Series[0].DataSource = dataList;
        testChart_2.Series[0].ArgumentDataMember = "Week";
        testChart_2.Series[0].ValueDataMembers.AddRange(new string[] { "PerformanceData" });

        testChart_2.Height = panel_bottom.Height;
        testChart_2.Width = panel_bottom.Width;


        //
        //Issue with blank chart rendering on calls to PerformCallback only happens if we add  testChart_2 
        //panel_bottom.Controls.Add(testChart_2);
        //


        customersDropDown.Attributes.Add("onChange", "panel_bottom.PerformCallback();");
    }
```

The method behind the panel's CallBack:

```
  protected void panel_bottom_callBack(object sender, CallbackEventArgsBase e)
{
    string customer_id = customersDropDown.SelectedValue;
    List<DataWeekRecord> data = new List<DataWeekRecord>();

    //Get new data based on customersDropDown.SelectedValue

    WebChartControl wbc = new WebChartControl();

    wbc.Series.Add(new DevExpress.XtraCharts.Series("Test Series", DevExpress.XtraCharts.ViewType.Line));
    wbc.Series[0].ArgumentScaleType = DevExpress.XtraCharts.ScaleType.DateTime;
    wbc.Series[0].ValueScaleType = DevExpress.XtraCharts.ScaleType.Numerical;

    wbc.Series[0].DataSource = data;
    wbc.Series[0].ArgumentDataMember = "Week";
    wbc.Series[0].ValueDataMembers.AddRange(new string[] { "PerformanceData" });

    wbc.Width = ASPxCallbackPanel.Width;
    wbc.Height = ASPxCallbackPanel.Height;

    ASPxCallbackPanel cbp = (ASPxCallbackPanel)sender;
    cbp.Controls.Add(wbc);
}
```

I've basically modified the steps I found on the page https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument7555, but instead of associating the `panel.PerformCallback()` with the button's Click event, I've associated it with the `DropDownList`'s `onChange` client-side event.

Lastly, it should be known I don't have much experience doing front end work.

Answer (score 0):

try calling wbc.DataBind() after you specify the DataSource for the chart and before you add it to the cbp callback panel in the panel_bottom_callBack handler. Also, looks like the testChart_2 is missing the DataBind() call in the Page_Load either.